# LetsEncrypt for SQL Server on Linux

Tags: server, sql, letsencrypt

I have found information on

- how to install LetsEncrypt on Linux for NGINX (which works)
- how to install LetsEncrypt for SQL Server on Windows (which relies on GUI tools so is of no use), and
- how to install other certificates for SQL Server on Linux

but I can't find ANYTHING about LetsEncrypt for SQL Server on Linux. No matter what I try I get this error message:
 `Error: 49940, Severity: 16, State: 1.Unable to open one or more of the user-specified certificate file(s). Verify that the certificate file(s) exist with read permissions for the user and group running SQL Server.`

It seems this should be possible, can anyone provide some tips?
[Edit]
I have verified that the two LetsEncrypt files have appropriate permissions. I copied and renamed them and they are pointed to by the tlscert and tlskey keys in the network section of /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf.

```
[network]
tlscert = /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem
tlskey = /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key
tlsprotocols = 1.2
forceencryption = 1
```

One thing not clear to me is whether the Letsencrypt private key in .pem format needs to be extracted to a .key file, so I have tried it both ways. I get the same error either way. 
These errors show up in the mssql/log/errorlog file.

Here are the resulsts asked for

```
ls -l  /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem:
-rw------- 1 mssql mssql 3586 May  3 22:20 /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem
ls -l  /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key
-rw------- 1 mssql mssql 1679 May  3 22:42 /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key
```

mssql.pem was originally fullchain.pem and mssql.key was originally privkey.pem, which are the files required by Nginx and which work for it.

Comment: This would indicate that you probably have a file permission error on the file which contains the certificate.  You would need to determine which file it is, and what permissions need to be.  I would suggest seeing if `systemctl status mysql` or `mysqld` indicates the file, or if entering `mysql` at the command lines does.  Failing that, you could examine `/var/log` to see if sql logs are there somewhere, hout `journalctl -b` to check those error logs.

Comment: thanks for your questions; I have amended my original question with more details. And please note this is mssql not mysql

Comment: K - please include the output of `ls -l tlscert = /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem` and `ls -l tlskey = /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key`

Comment: please see additional edit

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/896686/mariadb-ssl-configuration-using-lets-encrypt-certificate?noredirect=1#comment1158642_896686) particularly the accepted answer?

Comment: Thank you Charles, I hadn't seen that answer. I will try it first thing in the morning!

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! If you'd like to suggest that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrased from [MariaDB SSL configuration - using Let's Encrypt certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/896686/mariadb-ssl-configuration-using-lets-encrypt-certificate?noredirect=1#comment1158642_896686)

> The key is in the wrong format, and can be converted with openssl to
>   different format.
>
> ```
> openssl rsa -in ./privkey.pem -out ./privkeyrsa.pem
> ```
>
> And after tweaking permissions (0400) and ownership of that file
>   (mysql:mysql) SSL works as desired. (and of course config line to
>   point to the right cert)